# Jquery IE6 hover problems, keeps loading background image

Tags: jquery, hover, background-image, internet-explorer-6

Take a look at this page: http://pearl.tinderfields.com/

In IE6 the menu's background image loads every time the user hovers over a menu item, which is obviously making a very rubbish looking menu.

Is there any special reason as to why IE6 would re-load the image on every hover?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Read This:**

> http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/communityengine/index.cfm?event=showdetails&productId=1&postId=1104

```
<script type="text/javascript">
try {
 document.execCommand('BackgroundImageCache', false, true);
} catch(e) {}
</script>
```

OR try CSS way

```
html { 
filter: expression(document.execCommand("BackgroundImageCache", false, true)); 
}
```

hope this help!

Comment: Worked perfectly, your a modern day hero.